# Where do the 'nine rivers meet'?

Tags: second-coming

Where (Bible?) are we told where the nine rivers meet?  Are the rivers actual rivers or is it a metaphor?  How are the nine rivers linked to the number 13433?

Comment: What nine rivers? If you're thinking of a specific Bible quote, please put in a chapter and verse, together with the actual text of the verse (including which Bible translation you got it from). And why do you feel there should be a connection with 13,433? [Edit] the question and put that information in. Then we can tell you whether this is an answerable question for this site.

Comment: Matt, thank you for responding.  That's just it, I don't know which rivers they are.  Again the number is linked but I don't know how.  I have Googled this to distraction but not finding the answer.  I have read that in the Bible a river could be referring to a nation or a group of people(?); I've had no joy following this line.  The only reference  can find is an opera. 'The Nine Rivers from Jordan' which is an allegory about free will.

Comment: But where did you hear about "nine rivers"? We can't really respond to this unless we know where you originally heard about nine rivers, and why you think there's a connection with the number you're asking about.

Comment: [The Internet](https://www.google.com/search?safe=strict&rlz=1C1GGRV_enUS751US752&ei=1U_6WbrZDsrGjwSKwa_ICw&q=%22nine+rivers+meet%22+13433&oq=%22nine+rivers+meet%22+13433&gs_l=psy-ab.3...21219.22010.0.22237.5.5.0.0.0.0.230.433.2-2.2.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..3.0.0....0.LjNGKo4fkYk) certainly has a lot to say on the matter.

Comment: According to ddg search "nine rivers" "second coming", I found a .doc file about China in the Bible. It talks about the four rivers in Eden, then says the Chinese province "Sichuan originally had four rivers which then divided into nine rivers." Is this possibly related? Note: the site is ye-su.cn and the url has Chinese characters.

Comment: It is my considered belief that this question has little or nothing to do with the Bible.  I suspect the reference comes from Irishman Denis Johnston's book *Nine Rivers from Jordan, The Chronicle of a Journey and a Search* [full text link](https://archive.org/stream/nineriversfromjo006116mbp/nineriversfromjo006116mbp_djvu.txt).  The quotation comes from a "palm reading" the author experienced in egypt and he credits the first two rivers of the nine he was exptected to cross as the Jordan and the Nile.  The book is filled with Biblical allusion and I suspect that's were the connection started.

Answer (score 2):

OK, for the purpose of full disclosure before this question is closed and borrowing heavily from my original comment....

***Nine Rivers from Jordan, The Chronicle of a Journey and a Search* by [Denis Johnston](https://archive.org/stream/nineriversfromjo006116mbp/nineriversfromjo006116mbp_djvu.txt)**

I suspect the reference comes from Irishman Denis Johnston's book *Nine Rivers from Jordan, The Chronicle of a Journey and a Search.* The quotation comes from a "palm reading" the author experienced in egypt and he credits the first two rivers of the nine he was exptected to cross as the Jordan and the Nile. The book is filled with Biblical allusion and I suspect that's were the connection started.

HOWEVER, then I found the following on Reddit, which is far more likely to be the source of the reference, and it has absolutely nothing at all to do with the Bible or Christianity.

**A conversation from [REDDIT](https://www.reddit.com/r/Advice/comments/771t0m/where_do_the_nine_rivers_meet/?sort=old)**

> Where do the nine rivers meet? *submitted 15 days ago by RashChrysemys*
>
> Probably Jiujiang. Is there any context for this question? *Another_Solipsist 1 point 15 days ago*
>
> Yes, I had a dream in which I was in a church graveyard standing over a blank headstone, and as I look down at the headstone, at the bottom it says 13433 and the numbers disappear as I read them; then in the dream I look up and see a tall dark figure in a hood, but it looks like no one is actually inside the cloak, just a dark shadow or mist. The figure then points at me and says in some deep voice to “go to where the nine rivers meet” and I want to find out if there is a place in real life where nine rivers meet.  *RashChrysemys[S] 2 points 14 days ago*
>
> Neat.  Well, that's the only nine rivers legend I know of. Do you have any idea what the numbers mean, or is it all one big mystery?  *Another_Solipsist 1 point 14 days ago*
>
> Well so far, I’ve been convinced that I’m going to die at the age of 63, as that is how old I will be if you translate it into a date (British format) *RashChrysemys[S] 1 point 14 days ago*

**The Dictionary of [Lahu](https://books.google.com/books?id=YNA-g3an1uEC&pg=PA252&lpg=PA252&dq=%22nine+rivers+meet%22&source=bl&ots=Mxm2n8M2yg&sig=zLAwrxzvA6G5-CYV35ATxGMsHm4&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwin6bfylJ_XAhUU8mMKHSISA-EQ6AEISjAJ#v=onepage&q=%22nine%20rivers%20meet%22&f=false)**

This dictionary has a native phrase that translates to...

> Confluence of nine rivers; place where nine rivers meet (in animist heaven) [see subentry] ... We desire eternal life (prob. mean 'nine rivers';)

*If the Reddit OP ever finds this connection and since he already believes he'll die on April 13, 2033 (13/4/33), he'll probably see this as confirmation of his death (eternal life in heaven).  It's a wonderful case of illogical logic, but I'd bet a milkshake on it.*

**The [Mekong Delta](http://en.citizendium.org/wiki/Mekong_Delta)**

> It contains the Vietnamese provinces of Long An, Tien Gang, Bien Tre, Dong Thap, An Giang, Vinh Long, Kien Giang, Phong Binh, Hau Giang and Minh Hai. [1] Under French administration, the region was called Cochin China. Can Tho Province is the center of the region, where the nine rivers meet.

This last, the Vietnemese Mekong Delta reference, is undoubtadly the least likely culprit.

*And unless deleted, it's nice to know this answer will go down in mystery history as contributing to the mysterious "place where nine rivers meet" and the number 13433.*